# Debug libcef.dll while running a host app that uses cefsharp

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

We did a custom DEBUG build for cef version 84.1.1 to add codec support, and I am able to add a debug point to the libcef code (e.g. to file \cef\libcef_dll\libcef_dll2.cc) and attach the visual studio debugger to the sample cefclient.exe.

We have a .Net application, which uses CefSharp nuget 84.1.1, we just replace the cef dlls with the dlls that we built. When I run my host app, and I add a breakpoint, I keep getting the message that no matching assemblies were loaded. I tried attaching to all browsersubprocess instances, and I tried attaching to my app host process with no result.

Comment: Did you build a debug version of CefSharp? Please edit your original question and provide more detail.

Comment: hi @amaitland .. I updated the question a little bit. Regarding CefSharp, I am using the nuget as is, but the cef dlls I copied them from debug folder and replaced the ones that comes with the nuget library.

Comment: CefSharp Nuget packages contain a version that's build against a release version of libcef,  if you build a debug version of CefSharp yourself it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that and update log here if needed

Comment: Actually I tried again to add a debug point to (\cef\libcef_dll\libcef_dll2.cc) and this time I tried running and attaching to the debug version of CefSharp.WinForms.Example x86 (branch 84) after I copied the cef dlls which I build. I still get no assemblies loaded.

Comment: Your build likely differs in some way, try copying over the libcef_dll_wrapper.lib and libcef.lib files from your build into the cef.sdk Nuget package. Make sure the build processes isn't overriding your files also. Comment out the relevant target https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/84/CefSharp.Native.props#L11

Comment: I'm assuming you've copied the pdb file.

Comment: pdb files were not copied ... i copied all pdb files now including libcef.dll.pdb. but still no luck. As for rebuilding the code ... I got lots of linking errors in CefSharp.Core and I am still trying to figure out the issue .. I tried copying cef.sdk.84.4.1\CEF\include as well .. but didn't seem to fix the linking issues

Comment: Just to close this. I was never able to do the debug on CEF c++ code while running a .NET app that uses CefSharp wrapper even when i copied over the pdb files. However I don't need to debug it now, so I don't think I will update this post further.